# Removing unwanted comma while pasting multiple columns into one column in R code

Tags: r

I have four columns Associated_Doll1: Associated_Doll4

Associated_Doll1  | Associated_Doll2   | Associated_Doll3   |Associated _Doll4

```
 Doll_Hair         Doll_hand           Doll_body               Doll_Leg
 RED               WHITE                  NA                    NA
 NA                NA                    Apple                 Orange
```

Achieved Output column

```
Doll_Hair,Doll_Hand,Doll_body,Doll_leg
RED,WHITE
Apple,Orange
```

Code:

```
for(i in 1:length(B$Associated_Doll1))
{
B$Doll[i]<-paste(na.omit(c(B$Associated_Doll1[i],
B$Associated_Doll2[i],
B$Associated_Doll3[i],
B$Associated_Doll4[i],
B$Associated_Doll5[i])),collapse = ",")
}

B$Doll <- gsub(",NA,",",",B$Doll)

B$Doll <- gsub(",NA","",B$Doll)

B$Doll <- gsub("NA,","",B$Doll)
```

The above code works pretty fast for small data set around 1000 rows but I want the same operation to be done better in terms of speed for large data set(1000000 - observation with 10 columns)
How to improvise the same?? 
please suggest

Comment: Why do you `collapse` with `,` then? Maybe I don't understand it

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to create a new column at the end which combines the strings for each row from columns 1:5 seperated by a comma and the NA's removed?

Comment: yes ! Correct @Numb3rs

Comment: @DineshKumarV think User2321's answer is the solution to your question. If you agree, please accept his answer by clicking the tick mark on its left.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following (Thanks to @JanLauGe for the sample df):

```
df <- data.frame(
     hair = c('RED', NA),
     hand = c('WHITE', NA),
     body = c(NA, 'Apple'),
     leg = c(NA, 'Orange'))

df$totals <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ","))

> df
  hair  hand  body    leg       totals
1  RED WHITE  <NA>   <NA>    RED,WHITE
2 <NA>  <NA> Apple Orange Apple,Orange
```

Comment: This code is working, how do I apply for my large data set, in above example df is just 4 column but in my case, I have 10 columns in which I have to carry this work for the column 6:9 and to produce the result in the same df as 11th column pls suggest

Comment: Is der any way to avoid cbind in this case so that i dont want to have separate data  frame from this work rather I will produce this totals column in main_df itself@JanLauGe

Comment: Hi! The solution is not column dependent, instead of using this df use your data set, it should work fine!

Comment: my data set have other variables as well like Area ,State , Company , Hair ,Hand,Body ,leg in such case how to select these specific columns from my data set (Hand,body,hair,leg) and perform

Comment: d=B$totals <- B[,.(apply(B[,.c(9:13),], 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ",")))] ->>1.I used this code but it give me separate list as output 2. I convert it into Data table than I did cbind with main data set. Is there any way to produce the result in main data set ?

Comment: Well if B is your main data frame and you want the result for the columns 9-13 as you mentioned then: `B$totals <- apply(B[, c(9:13)], 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ","))` should do the trick.

Comment: In case this does not work for you then I need more info: `dput(head(B))` would be a good start and you need to provide the columns that need to be used by the function (in the first comment you mention 6-9 and in the code part you used 9-13).

Answer (score 0):

The `stringr` package is your friend:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df <- data_frame(
  hair = c('RED', NA),
  hand = c('WHITE', NA),
  body = c(NA, 'Apple'),
  leg = c(NA, 'Orange')
)

df %>%
  # Replace NA's with empty strings
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace_na(., replacement = ''))) %>%
  # Create new, joined column
  mutate(joined = str_c(hair, hand, body, leg))
```

Comment: I don't get any commas in between strings above codes give the string (REDWHITE,,) but i expected the output to be (RED,WHITE)